# c# Stream OpenFile & Process Run

Tags: c#

I want button6 & button2
select the file , and the start button starts the 2 selected files

[image]

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // road
    {

        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Road.Service (Road.Service.exe)|Road.Service.exe|Road.Service|Road.Service.exe";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;



        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //center
    {

        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Center.Service (Center.Service.exe)|Center.Service.exe|Center.Service|Center.Service.exe";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;



        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {

                    }
                }

            }


            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //start
    {
        Process.Start(button6 , button2);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attempt to launch the processes after they have selected them, save their file paths to variables inside your form, and in your `button5_Click` method call `Process.Start` on each of them.

You can get the file names using `OpenFileDialog.FileName`

Edit with code:

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    roadFilePath = fileopenFileDialog.FileName;
}
```

where roadFilePath is a private variable on your form. Then you would call `Proccess.Start(roadFilePath)`

Comment: Process.Start(button5_Click, button2_Click);?